# Round off the values in a list in jinja

Tags: sorting, flask, jinja2, rounding

I have a dictionary as

```
dictionary_num = {'Age': [-1.0, 25.0], 'M2': [-1.0, 42.0], 'younChild': [-1.0, 7.0], 'M4': [-1.0, 216.0]}
```

and another dictionary as

```
dictionary_mcqsr = {'M5': [-1.0, 3.0, 0.0, 2.0, 1.0], 'M6': [-1.0, 0.0, 1.0], 'M7': [-1.0, 1.0, 0.0], 'M8A': [0.0, -1.0, 1.0, 2.0], 'M8B': [1.0, 0.0, -1.0], 'M9': [0, 1], 'M11': [0, 1], 'M12': [2, 1, 0, -1]}
```

which is rendered as

```
{% for key,value in dictionary_num.items() %}
                        {% if key == j %}
                            <td>{{value}}</td>
                        {% endif %}
              {% endfor %}
{% for key,value in dictionary_mcqsr.items() %}
                            {% if key == j %}
                                <td>{{value}}</td>
                            {% endif %}
                  {% endfor %}
```

where j refers to the keys. When I render it, I want to remove the decimal points at the jinja side in both dictionary_num and dictionary_mcqsr and sort the values for dictionary_mcqsr but could not find any solution.

Answer (score 0):

Use a filter around what you want to round off :

Example : (for a single element)

```
{{ (value)|round|int }}
```

EDIT : For the list :

```
{% for key,value in dictionary_num.items() %}
                        {% if key == j %}
                            <td>[{% for element in value %} {{ (element.value)|round|int }}{% if not loop.last %},{% endif %} {% endfor %}]</td>
                        {% endif %}
              {% endfor %}
{% for key,value in dictionary_mcqsr.items() %}
                            {% if key == j %}
                                <td>[{% for element in value %} {{ (element.value)|round|int }}{% if not loop.last %},{% endif %} {% endfor %}]</td>
                            {% endif %}
                  {% endfor %}
```

Comment: `value` is a list. Therefore it gives me an error `TypeError: type list doesn't define __round__ method`

Comment: `File "C:\kuhuconfig\templates\pages\placeholder.results.html", line 1, in top-level template code
    {% extends 'layouts/main.html' %} {% block title %}Codesheet{% endblock %} {% block content %}
    File "C:\kuhuconfig\templates\layouts\main.html", line 122, in top-level template code
    {% endfor %} {% endif %} {% endwith %} {% block content %}{% endblock %}
    File "C:\kuhuconfig\templates\pages\placeholder.results.html", line 60, in block "content"

    {{ (element.value) | round | int }
    TypeError: type Undefined doesn't define __round__ method`         It throws this error.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`sort`](http://jinja.pocoo.org/docs/2.10/templates/#sort) and `round` filter in Jinja.

```
{% for key, value in dictionary_num.items() %}
    {% if key == j%}
        <td>
        [
            {% for element in value %}
                {{ element.value | round | int }}
                {% if not loop.last%}
                    ,
                {% endif %}
            {% endfor %}
        ]
    {% endif %}
{% endfor %}
{% for key, value in dictionary_mcqsr.items() %}
    {% if key == j%}
        <td>
        [
            {% for element in value | sort %}
                {{ element.value | round | int }}
                {% if not loop.last%}
                    ,
                {% endif %}
            {% endfor %}
        ]
    {% endif %}
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: File "C:\kuhuconfig\templates\pages\placeholder.results.html", line 1, in top-level template code {% extends 'layouts/main.html' %} {% block title %}Codesheet{% endblock %} {% block content %} File "C:\kuhuconfig\templates\layouts\main.html", line 122, in top-level template code {% endfor %} {% endif %} {% endwith %} {% block content %}{% endblock %} File "C:\kuhuconfig\templates\pages\placeholder.results.html", line 60, in block "content" {{ (element.value) | round | int } TypeError: type Undefined doesn't define __round__ method It throws this error.